# How to analyze the memory-Leak in the android Studio

Tags: android, memory-leaks

After I finished from my App, I did a test for Leak activity. I have found my App has a Leak but the leak is not showing all the time.

How to analyze the Reference Tree?

My Screenshots:

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing memory leaks and fixing them is for every project different it is good to get the understanding about how to analyze them and how to solve them. There are some great tutorials available online, look for Memory leaks android, or Intellij detection/analyze. Enough material.

It is good to have the knowledge and know what the values means in the analyze screen. For instance https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/intellij-idea-profiler-example/

Comment: Ok great .. I will check the link